# In Apigee how do I route all content with a specific prefix to another service

Tags: apigee

I want to configure my proxy in the following fashion.

- All requests by default get passed through to http://main.api.com
- Any request that has has a URI path that start /admin gets routed to http://admin.api.com

`<RouteRule name="mocker">
    <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix JavaRegex "^/admin/?.*$")</Condition>
    <TargetEndpoint>MockTarget</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="default">
    <TargetEndpoint>default</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>`

This partially works in that it does indeed route to a different host. However, it maintains the path; so requesting /admin/foo/bar gets redirected to http://admin.api.com/admin/foo/bar, but I wanted it to go to http://admin.api.com/foo/bar

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set `target.copy.pathsuffix` to `false` in the Target PreFlow. This will ensure that the path from Proxy is not copied to the Target.

You can easily do this by adding a Javascript policy on the Target Preflow with the code

```
context.setVariable("target.copy.pathsuffix", false);
```